# SSRS 2008R2: How we can hide X-axis label in line chart?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am new in SSRS world.

I have set the X-axis label interval '1' and Interval Type 'day'. It is working properly. Now I want to hide the all label Except the 1st, 15th,31th Date of every month. Is it possible to set the expression in hide properties for X-axis?

Can anyone help me regarding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #2**
Open the `Category Group properties` - there you will have the option to define expression to the labal. Then use the following expression:

`Switch(Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 31 , "31", Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value)> 1 AND Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) < 14 , " ", Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 15 , "15", Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) > 15 AND Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) < 30, " ", Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 30 , "30")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not workinng. I have used below expression in Axis Label 'Hide properties':

Comment: Switch(Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 31 , false, Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value)> 1 AND Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) < 14 , true , Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 15 , false, Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) > 15 AND Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) < 30, true, Day(Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value) = 30 , true)

Comment: Actually it set Hide properties to 'false' for X-axis. Above I have used Field. Is it possible that, I can use axis label value  in Expression? If possible how?

Comment: Again it is not working. It is taking the "black" for all the labels.

Comment: Same reuslt again. I have change it and use IIF (Day (Fields!SAMPLE_DATE.Value)< 10,"Black","White")  but it is taking Black for all label font..

Comment: If it is working for you can you please provide me one sample exampel or screen shot?

Comment: I'm sorry for all the long way, but this is A **working solution** - check My update Answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it working fine. Great work and thanks again.